# Filter hierarchical data and remove empty nodes

Tags: algorithm, tree, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have the following hierarchical data structure:

```
const tree = [
    { 
        node: true,
        key: 1,
        children: [
          {
            node: true,
            key: 2,
            children: [
              { leaf: true, key: 1 },
              { leaf: true, key: 2 }
              //...
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
    ///
];
```

I'd like to filter only items that marked as `leaf`. Then, I need to remove nodes, that have no leaves.

For example, if filter criterion is `key > 2`, the result should be empty.

I've tried to use a recursive function, but have no positive result.

Comment: These are basic operations on a record (filter) and a tree (removal), documented well in texts and on line.  Where are you stuck in applying those descriptions?

Comment: I can't remove **all** nodes without leaves.

Comment: @Prune could you share the article or doc that describes how to implement such a fucntionality?